# nodeenv - inside virtualenv but installing to global node packages

Tags: node.js, virtualenv

**UPDATE: npm was in fact installing within the virtualenv. However, deactivating the virtualenv and then calling npm list still shows the npm from the virtualenv. That was the source of my confusion. Opening an entirely new terminal window and running npm list to view the global npm installs shows the correct info.**

I've created a virtualenv

`mkproject MyProject`

... then installed nodeenv inside of the virtualenv

`(MyProject) pip install nodeenv`

Both node and npm are local to the virtualenv, but somehow npm packages are still being installed to the global node modules

`(MyProject)which node` --> "its/the/path/to/MyProject/bin/node"

`(MyProject)which npm` --> likewise... "bin/npm"

**However** `npm install` still results in the modules being installed to the global node packages...

`(MyProject)npm install less`

after installation: `(MyProject)which less` --> gives me the global node modules path

How can I limit the npm installs to the virtualenv?

Comment: Just checking did you switch to the env correctly ? You have to run `. nodeenv/bin/activate`. See the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv)

Comment: It was active within a virtualenv wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit too late, but hope it helps.

```
mkvirtualenv projectname

pip install nodeenv

nodeenv -p
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using nodeenv (as enticing as it might be since it would work with your python virtual env) try using nave instead.

```
mkvirtualenv projectname
nave use stable
nave use projectname stable
npm install -g sailsjs passport passport-persona
```

Then you can edit the `~/.virtualenv/projectname/postactivate` to include that nave activate

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
...
nave use projectname stable
...
```